# how to override index query during runtime and update the table laravel-nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

in my use case, I need more than one text box for searching in more than two fields in the index view at the same time, because there too much data, laravel-nova provide only one out of the box, so if there is a way that I can add search in a card and update the index query in run time it will be great, and if there are any other solutions for this problem I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel Migration:**

Create the migration files to set up index queries.

In the function, wherever you needed, use the below command to run the migration.

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('--path' => 'app/migrations', '--force' => true));
```

Here, you can also specify the migration file name like,

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('--path' => 'app/migrations/create_index.php', '--force' => true));
```

Comment: how can I update the index query depending on user input text field during runtime with migration please if you clarify it with a simple example it would help

Comment: Based on your business logic, use if statements and run the migration accordingly.

Comment: where I can put this code that causes the page to reload the index table? the way that I was doing it before page loading was overriding indexQuery() method now in run time where can i put the code that you have written above and how the migration query and the index query will be connected ? please help

Comment: before I used migrations only for creating tables instead of writing SQL code never used it for such things!